# is motherboard compatible with video card

Tags: motherboard, graphics-card

is this motherboard

[http://www.amazon.com/GIGABYTE-GA-EP45-UD3P-LGA-Intel-Motherboard/dp/tech-data/B001HH2WE2/ref=de_a_smtd](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001HH2WE2)

compatible with this video card

[http://www.amazon.com/Sapphire-Radeon-100252HDMI-PCI-Express-Graphics/dp/B001SJLLTQ/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1267409861&sr=1-1-fkmr0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001SJLLTQ)

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The video card uses PCI-Express and so does the motherboard.